# Protractor - configure window size of headless chrome within Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, protractor

It seems like the window-size of a headless chrome couldn't be configured.
Some components of my application are only visible if the width is bigger than 960px, but protractor couldn't find them. If I run the test without "--headless"-attribute everything works fine.
Does anyone solve this problem?

Node Version: 6.10.1
Protractor Version: 5.11
Angular Version: 1.5.8
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System and Version: Ubuntu 16.04
Your protractor configuration file:

```
capabilities{ browserName: 'chrome', chromeOptions:{ 
       args:[ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1000,1000" ] 
} }
```

Solution:

The window size of a headless browser isn't configureable. 
I used a jenkins slave to a ubuntu machine with head.

Comment: Instead of passing `--window-size` as chrome arguments,try to set the window size using protractor itself. Inside the `onPrepare` method in config file use `browser.manage().window().setSize(1000,1000)` will do the trick for you.

Comment: Your trick was my first configuration but it also didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use chrome browser version >=58 and config:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': process.env.PROTRACTOR_BROWSER || 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1000x1000']
    }
  }
```

It's work well for me.

Comment: with 1000x1000 or 1000,1000?